# How would I embed a responsive playable youtube video inside this image?

Tags: html, css, video, embed

How would I embed a responsive playable youtube video into this tv? (Preferably not on autoplay).

I'm having a hard time with this and was wondering if anyone can help. Thank you.

```css
.tv {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 550px/2);
  top: calc(50% - 380px/2);
}

.tv img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 550px;
}

.video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 20px;
}



.b {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="tv">
  <img src="http://honeypotmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/OLD-SCHOOL-TV.png" alt="" />
  <!-- broken video -->
  <div class="video">
        <video class="b" src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" autoplay></video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For responsiveness you need to add css for div  heigh:auto and width in % not pixels, like:

```
style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"
```

Hope it works.
Thanks :)